# WP_enqueue_script() loads them always in wp_footer()?

Tags: widgets, jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

This is my example code placed in functions.php:

```
function my_init_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-widget', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-mouse', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-accordion', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-slider', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-sortable', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-draggable', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-droppable', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-selectable', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    //wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-resizable', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-dialog', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    //wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-button', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
}
add_action('init', 'my_init_method');
```

Here is the reference: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Why all scripts except jQuery are loading in `wp_footer()` and not `wp_head()`? I set last parameter to `false`. I also tried `true` and I tried completely deleting parameters like: `wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');`. Yet, they always load in footer.

Comment: I believe and could be wrong, but as they have been registered already, when enqueueing them with no src will trigger WP to look at the registered details rather than your item. Similarly, you should be using the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. Lastly, it's considered a best practice to load your JS in the footer for page speed.

Comment: any specific reason to enqueue them on head?

Comment: @Sisir Yes, it says $.widget doesn't exist when I load in footer. It doesn't say that when I load in head.

Comment: @Sneek I can't load $.widget after I want to use it. I need to load it in head and use in body. Otherwise it returns error. How can I overwrite WP settings then?

Comment: did you tried using `jQuery` instead of `$`? The error is showing probably because your js script loading on head (before jquery or other jquery ui files). Also you should hook into `wp_enqueue_scripts` not into `init`

Comment: Yes, I tried `$` and `jQuery`. I have to load jQuery Widget BEFORE I use it. I'm sure. I moved everything to `wp_enqueue_scripts` but it didn't change anything. In admin panel (and on front page) I have $.widget not defined. When I manually load jQuery widget in head - it works!

Comment: The code to instantiate your jQuery objects should be dependant on which ever library you are using. Thus if you `wp_enqueue_script` your scripts and pass in the dependiency array the relevant library like 'jquery-ui-dialog', and load your script in the footer; everything should work as intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of these scripts are already registered to print in the footer. See `wp-includes/script-loader.php` for details. When you try to register the scripts again WordPress doesn’t change that.

The workaround would be to register a new script for `wp_head` with those scripts as dependencies (the third parameter of `wp_enqueue_script()`).

Do not register the scripts in another order before WP does it! This will affect `wp-admin` and probably other pages too.

But the real question is: Why do you need the scripts loaded so early? Fix *that* instead. My guess: You are using some inline script and don’t wait until the document is loaded. That is hardly ever necessary.

Also note that `$` is **not** a jQuery object in WordPress. 
You have to use `jQuery( function( $ ) { /* your code with $ here. */ }`.

Comment: "You are using some inline script and don’t wait until the document is loaded." - I use document ready or window load everywhere but I will check that. Whenever I load jQuery Widget in footer - it breaks ($.widget not defined). If you say that I can load it in footer and still maintain my original code with document load check then I'll check all my scripts once again. Maybe I missed document ready check somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: @Flow See my update. You cannot use `$` in the global namespace without preparation in WordPress.

Comment: Yes, yes, I use jQuery() everywhere :) Otherwise, it breaks. Alternatively, I use this hack: `$ = jQuery.noConflict();`. I'll check if you were right today and let you know here by choosing it as best answer!

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you need to hook into `wp_enqueue_scripts`. You also need to enqueue the scripts before any other part of WordPress enqueues them, because [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) "includes the script if it hasn't already been included". If the script would already be included, I believe you wouldn't be able to change it's position from footer to head.

So the working code could look like this:

```php
function my_enqueue_scripts_method() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-widget', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-mouse', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-accordion', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-slider', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-tabs', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-sortable', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-draggable', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-droppable', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-selectable', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    //wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-datepicker', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-resizable', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-dialog', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
    //wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-button', false, array('jquery'), false, false);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts_method', 1);
```

EDIT: But as @toscho said, this just fixes your most-likely-broken way of handling your own script. This stuff should be loaded in the footer for maximum performance.